# Nginx cannot serve css files because of MIME type error

Tags: linux, webserver, nginx, css, mime-types

**My Setup:**

It is a nginx/gunicorn setup for django webapp.

Here is my nginx config file:

```
worker_processes 1;

user ubuntu nogroup; # for systems with a "nogroup"
# user nobody nobody; # for systems with "nobody" as a group instead

# Feel free to change all paths to suit your needs here, of course
pid /tmp/nginx.pid;
error_log /tmp/nginx.error.log;

events {
  worker_connections 1024; # increase if you have lots of clients
  accept_mutex off; # "on" if nginx worker_processes > 1
  use epoll; # enable for Linux 2.6+
  # use kqueue; # enable for FreeBSD, OSX
}

http {

  # fallback in case we can't determine a type
  default_type application/octet-stream;

  # click tracking!
  access_log /tmp/nginx.access.log combined;

  # you generally want to serve static files with nginx since neither
  # Unicorn nor Rainbows! is optimized for it at the moment
  sendfile off;

  tcp_nopush off; # off may be better for *some* Comet/long-poll stuff
  tcp_nodelay off; # on may be better for some Comet/long-poll stuff


  # this can be any application server, not just Unicorn/Rainbows!
  upstream app_server {

    # for UNIX domain socket setups:
    server localhost:8080;

  }

  server {
    listen 8000;

#    client_max_body_size 4G;
    server_name _;

    proxy_connect_timeout 75s;
    proxy_send_timeout 75s;
    proxy_read_timeout 75s;

    expires -1;
    location /static {
        autoindex on;
        alias /home/ubuntu/mira_website/manageDb/static/;
    }


    location / {

      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

      proxy_redirect off;

      proxy_buffering off;

      proxy_pass http://app_server;

    }

    # Error pages
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    location = /500.html {
      root /path/to/app/current/public;
    }
  }
}
```

**Errors I am getting**

I am getting errors from the browser. Here are those:

```
/static/rest_framework_swagger/css/highlight.default.css was not loaded because its MIME type, "application/octet-stream", is not "text/css".
```

What's interesting is that `.js` files are successfully served. One more thing to note is that both `.js` and `.css` files were generated by django by doing `python manage.py collectstatic`.

Another interesting thing is that when I put `/static/rest_framework_swagger/css/highlight.default.css` directly in the url, it serves me the file for download.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Silly me. I forgot to put `include /etc/nginx/mime.types` in the configuration file. So I put it in `location /static {}` block and now it works.